# How to activate Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I am very new to `Anaconda` and `Miniconda`. In the [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) it says

> You may receive a warning message if you have not activated your environment:

`Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation.`

I receive this warning upton typing `$ python` in the `PowerShell`

The documentation further states:

> If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To do so on Windows, run: `c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base` in Anaconda Prompt.

What does that mean, "in Anaconda Prompt"? How do I properly activate the environment on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Usually once you install `conda` you need to run the command `conda activate base`. This command should only have to be run once and should fix your problem.